# How to filter query result to list of strings

Tags: list, linq

I have a query result same as below:

```
var ptns = from p in db.Patients
           select p;
```

This query returns a list of patients, but I need to filter the result based on `DoctorNameID`. The `DoctorNameID` should be in list of doctors as below:

```
 List<string> listofDoctors = usrtodrs.Split(',').ToList();
```

I have searched a lot but I don't know how to do this. I have tested this query which doesn't work:

```
var  ptns1 = from d in listofDoctors
             join p in ptns.ToList() on d equals p.DoctorNameID
             select p;
```

And also this query:

```
var ptns1  = ptns.ToList()
                 .Where(a => listofDoctors.Equals(a.DoctorNameID))
                 .ToList();
```

Any help?

Comment: **Yet another** of the great many reasons why having comma- or semicolon-separated lists of things is a **horribly bad idea** and should be avoided whenever possible!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Contains` extension and get the desired result.

```
var ptns1 = ptns.Where(x => listofDoctors.Contains(x.DoctorNameID)).ToList();
```

Refer the [C# Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ASxOws) with sample data.